# How to round down only numbers which are above 100 and ends with "05" - not using left and right formula

Tags: excel, formula

Formula is simple: =IF(CA4>1,CA4,CEILING(BT4*BY$2,5))

So I want to add in part of IF FALSE (CEILING) calculation which would round down numbers like 105, 205 to 100, 200 etc.

I know I can use some formula using RIGHT and LEFT, however I am wondering if there is mathematical solution...

Comment: I don't understand your problem completely. Can you give more examples of numbers (including those that don't end in '05') and what they should end up as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are happy with the results of your formula except where the latter part results in a figure greater than 100 and ending in 05, and in that case you want the result to be rounded down to the 100, then try this revised version

=IF(CA4>1,CA4,IF(MOD(BT4*BY$2,100)<=5,FLOOR(BT4*BY$2,100),CEILING(BT4*BY$2,5)))

Answer (score 0):

ROUNDDOWN worksheet function is what you are looking for.

Example code:

```
A = 105
B = 205

C = ROUNDDOWN(A,-2)
D = ROUNDDOWN(B,-2) 

MsgBox( "105 is Rounded down to " & C)
MsgBox( "205 is Rounded down to " & D)
```

This code will display as follows

105 is Rounded down to 100

205 is Rounded down to 200